# How to make Sequence evaluate?

Tags: f#

I'm working on my knowledge of F# and one problem I run in to repeatedly is when trying to create functions, if I use `Sequence` too close to the end result I end up printing the signature of the function instead of the output.

Example:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let consoleInput = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> System.Console.ReadLine())

    let isEmpty str = (not (str = System.Environment.NewLine)) && (not (str = "")) && (not (str = null))

    let inputs = consoleInput |> 
        Seq.takeWhile isEmpty |> 
        Seq.map (fun str -> System.Convert.ToInt32(str))

    let makeAbsolute lst = Seq.map (fun x -> abs x)

    let values = makeAbsolute inputs

    printfn "%A" values

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

All this is supposed to do is take in N inputs and output them as absolute values. However at the end it prints out the function signature - .

I don't want to call Seq.toList just to evaluate the sequence because it seems inelegant, so is there a 'right way' to be doing this kind of thing?

Edit: Besides my rather cheeky use of 'inelegance', I also want to keep the function as generic as possible (just a habit born of resharper use and my style of development), and using tolist is making the function 'more specific' which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't actually calling `Seq.map` with the sequence argument, your `makeAbsolute` function takes a parameter `lst` but doesn't do anything with it.

Give the sequence to the function and it will evaluate the results.

```
let makeAbsolute lst = Seq.map (fun x -> abs x) lst
```

Note that you can also simplify this to:

```
let makeAbsolute lst = Seq.map (abs) lst
```

Comment: OH SHOOT! I'm a fool :( Literally just wrote a program using this and forgot the argument this time around.

Comment: I know I marked you off as answered, but as an aside, would you know how to get this line printing after the user has entered n numbers then an empty entry: `Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn "%d" x) values` (going back to that 'how do I evaluate a sequence correctly at a certain point in the program')

Comment: @CBauer at the moment, the way you've written it, it will evaluate the sequence in one pass, taking input then printing due to the lazy evaluation of sequences.  If you want to gather up the results before iterating to print the results, it's probably best to add a `Seq.toList` or equivalent in between the `map` and the `iter`.

Comment: @CBauer You could also do something like `values |> Seq.fold (sprintf "%s%d\n") "" |> printf "%s"` to entirely avoid `list`s if you fancy but I'd probably just go with the `toList`, I think it's easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate it!